# Как написать генератор чисел с линией тренда (сердцебиения) на js?

Tags: javascript, генерация-случайных-данных, генераторы

Написал простенький генератор который дает число в определенном диапазоне, но не знаю как добавить линию тренда сердцебиения. На выходе я хочу получить таблицу которая по которой строится кардиограмма.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Красный пунктир - линия тренда
Черная линия - построена по данным генератора (числа не могут превышать заданный лимит от линии тренда)

UPD 1. Вот пример кода, не знаю зачем он нужен :/

```js
function getRandomInRange(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

getRandomInRange(1, 10)
```

Comment: как линия тренда задается?

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, в свой вопрос код, который Вы используете на данный момент